# Could not find bugsnag plugin

Tags: react-native

I clone my project to windows pc ( until now worked on mac ).
After clone I run npm install.
When I trying to run react-native run-android I get error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Here is the full log after react-native run-android command.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1100 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:5.4.0-react-native.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/ionia/.m2/repository/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-android-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/ionia/Desktop/iCardApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-android-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/ionia/Desktop/iCardApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-android-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-android-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-android-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-android-5.4.0-react-native.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :bugsnag_react-native
   > Could not find com.bugsnag:bugsnag-plugin-react-native:5.4.0-react-native.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/ionia/.m2/repository/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-plugin-react-native/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-plugin-react-native-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/ionia/Desktop/iCardApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-plugin-react-native/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-plugin-react-native-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/ionia/Desktop/iCardApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-plugin-react-native/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-plugin-react-native-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-plugin-react-native/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-plugin-react-native-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-plugin-react-native/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-plugin-react-native-5.4.0-react-native.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/bugsnag/bugsnag-plugin-react-native/5.4.0-react-native/bugsnag-plugin-react-native-5.4.0-react-native.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :bugsnag_react-native

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081


C:\Users\ionia\Desktop\iCardApp>
```

Comment: Ever get this figured out?